# Losing meteor Instance in background

Tags: android, performance

I am using meteor in Android using DDP client. And I am creating instance of meteor using (Meteor Singleton). When My App is in background for longtime then I am loosing that instance, and while coming in foreground My App start crashing Until i create a new instance.So, is there is any possibility to save that instance while my app in background.

Comment: Where do you keep this instance and where are you creating it?

Comment: I am cresting Meteor instance in Login Activity. And I am using that instance in different activity by using MeteorSingleton.getInstance().This is working fine when I am in foreground.But I am losing that instance when my app is in background for long time